# How to pass data from the server to the client over UDP?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, udp, protocols

Why doesn't this work?

```
           Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ipserv = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.174.48.47"), 46535);
        IPEndPoint ipLoc = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("86.64.47.13"), 755);
        client.Connect(ipserv);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
        client.Send(data);
        client.Bind(ipLoc);
        client.Receive(data);
        Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Error:
An unhandled exception of type "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" System.dll
Additional information: Received invalid argument

I send to the server the text from the console and then want to get it back from the server. How to do it?

Comment: Server sending data on ipLoc

Answer (score 0):

I think IPAndress of sever and client are the same

Comment: Ports are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific about where the exception occurs. But, looking at the code, I would guess it happens on the `client.Bind()` method call. The reason being, that when you call `client.Send()`, the network layer at that time assigns your socket a port number. Your attempt then to call `Bind()` to assign the local IP address and port number would then fail, because the port number can't be changed and has already been assigned.

Your question is sparse on detail, but I would recommend that you not bother with the `ipLoc` at all. Only the server endpoint needs to have a fixed port number. It is better to let the client socket have its port (and IP address) assigned implicitly by the network layer.

If that does not address your question, please improve the question so that it includes a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and explain in more detail exactly what happens. Be sure to include the exact text of any error message and the full stack trace of any thrown exceptions.